# When i compare 00:00:00 (24 hours format ) using isAfter method it returns false

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am unable to compare range using the `isAfter` method. 
When i compare `00:00:00` (24 hours format), `isAfter` method consider it null and return false.

```
end = '00:00:00';
if(moment(end).isAfter(current_date_n_time)) {
    alert("true");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

In this case it always return false.

I want to expect it return true and control goes to if body

Comment: One of us is missing something - how (logically) can Midnight ever be after _any_ time? It can be after the previous day, but only if its part of a date, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: I want to render my calendar recuring events from current date but when user update any event to 23:00:00 and add duration of 30 minutes (event end time will become 00:00:00)

In javascript i put condition before rendering my event

eventRender: function(event, element){
      if(event.class == "students_calendar_event")
              {
                return (event.ranges.filter(function(range){
              return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) && event.end.isAfter(range.start));
                 
                }).length)>0;
            
              } 
            },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moment(end);` gives Invalid date, so you need to pass a format as second parameter like :
 `moment('00:00:00','HH:mm:ss');`
It will give the starting time of current date, so when you are comparing it with the current date and time you will get false as per your condition. Try changing `.isAfter` to `.isBefore` and then your execution will go into if block.

```
    const end = '00:00:00';

    if(moment(end,'hh:mm:ss').isBefore(new Date())) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
```

Find the demonstration [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shail_23/n4m5puer/).

Comment: Thank You CodeReady sir, This example works for me, I learnt new things